# Why the unhandled user-defined exception even when defined?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Trying to run this code:

```
1      declare
2       hq exception;
3       ll exception;
4       nom number;
5       cursor pq is select count(*) as units from test1;
6       hh  pq%ROWTYPE;
7      begin
8          open pq;
9          fetch pq into hh;
10          nom := hh.units;
11          if nom >1 then
12              RAISE hq;
13          else
14              RAISE ll;
15          end if;
16      exception
17          when hq then
18             raise_application_error (-20501 , 'error1');
19          when ll then
20             RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20500 , 'error2');
21   end;
abc@.US.ORACLE.COM>/
    declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20501: error1
ORA-06512: at line 18
ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception
```

Why am i getting this error on line 1? and where is the unhandled user-defined
exception? Exception handlers hq and ll are defined in the exception section .
Where am i wrong? Using Oracle 9iR2
Thanks

Comment: The code is working exactly how you coded it - it is raising `hq`, which is being handled by your exception handler, which raises ORA-20501. What else do you want it to do?

Comment: Thanks Robert Merkwürdigeliebe and Jeffrey.

Comment: Confused with ORA-06510. IF the exception was handled why this error? It should have stopped with ORA-06512? Does raise_application_error return an unhandled exception to sqlplus env? How do you correct it for ORA-06510?

Answer (score 2):

You are raising a user defined error yourself in the exception handler (raise_application_error). This user defined error is not handled by your code, so a unhandled  user-defined exception is thrown.

Comment: You mean to say raise_application_error should not be used inside exception section? How do you handle this error then?

Comment: @user1064227 As Jeffrey said, this code is doing exactly what you coded. What are you trying to achieve? You can handle the error by replacing the raise application error by code that handles the error.